# Get Serialize data of more than 1 models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

i have 3 model

```
class Camera(models.Model):
    CameraId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='CameraId')
    CameraName = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class DeviceType(models.Model):
    DeviceTypeId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='DeviceTypeId')
    DeviceType = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Device(models.Model):
    DeviceId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='DeviceId')
    DeviceName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CameraId = models.ForeignKey(Camera, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CameraId', 
                           related_name='cameras')
    DeviceTypeId = models.ForeignKey(DeviceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='DeviceTypeId')
```

i want result of Device serialize JSON data , related to  Device

```
{
   'DeviceId'   : DeviceId ,
   'DeviceName' : DeviceName ,
   'CameraId'   : CameraId,
   'CameraName': CameraName ,
   'DeviceTypeId' :DeviceTypeId ,
   'DeviceType'  :DeviceType 
}
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override your get_queryset method in your class based view (APIView or ListAPIView) with annotated queryset. Something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Device.objects.all().annotate(camera_name = F('camera__camera_name'), device_type = F('device_type__device_type'))
    return queryset
```

Dont forget to import F from from django.db.models

Also you should add camera_name and device_type fields to your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a get response,you can go for a generic api view,retrieve the device by id and in your get function you can have something like this :

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
...
 device = Device.objects.get(pk=pk_passed_in_url)
 return Response({
   'DeviceId':device.DeviceId,
   'DeviceName' : device.DeviceName,
   'CameraId' : device.CameraId,
   'CameraName' : device.CameraId.CameraName,
   'DeviceTypeId' : device.DeviceTypeId,
   'DeviceType' : device.DeviceTypeId.DeviceType
})
```